# Run time error code for c

Tags: windows-runtime, runtime, runtime-error

Is there any way to find the runtime error code for c. Like if our c program gets executed successfully then main returns "0" otherwise any nonzero value according to the error occurred. I want to know how to find that code returned by main on windows platform ?

Comment: How do you launch the program? Command line? Double-clicking icon? Powershell? From another program programmatically? How?

Comment: @hyde i want to run on command line